# Laravel redirect from one services to another service page

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to redirect one services page like /services/service-name to another /services/anoter-service.
I am doing like this but this not working

```
Route::get('/services/instragram-marketing', function () {
  return redirect('/services/facebook-marketing', 301);
});
```

Comment: try `Redirect::to`

Comment: no this not works

Comment: "not working" ... what do you expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::get('/services/instragram-marketing', function () {
    return \Redirect::to('/services/facebook-marketing');
 });
```

Maybe like this can work, if you using old version laravel.

Comment: What is your laravel version ?

Comment: laravel version 6.2.

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this.**

`return Redirect::route('/services/facebook-marketing');` and check your url.

Make sure your route `/services/facebook-marketing` is available or not in web.php. If you can pass your service name dynamically then try `Route::get('/services/{service_name}');`